# filtering dependencies requirejs

Tags: jquery, .net, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a backbone /jquery /underscore /requirejs application in my application and there are several levels of view hierarchy. One main view is rendering several subviews set in my config file and those subviews are rendering their subviews set in the config file too creating a hierarchy with the following syntax:

```
'MainView': { deps: ['MainCView'] },
'MainCView': { deps: ['MainContentBView', 'MainFooterView', 'MainHeaderView'] },
'MainContentBView': { deps: ['TopMenuView', 'AdvertView', 'ProductsContentView'] }
```

The reason I am doing that is because I want to have the configuration of my views in a single place in the entire application.

The question is how to filter those view dependencies based on some criteria after they are defined?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What do you mean by filtering? And does this mean you are not using the `define` -function at the start of these modules?

Comment: quite the opposite i am defining the views as modules and dinamically instantiating the modules without the parent view knowing which are its subviews at compile time (i know js is not compiled) the idea behind is that i want an application which is configured at only 1 place- the config.js file and i dont want to hard code the subview dependencies of views in the views themself

Comment: i hope i made it clearer now - the case is pretty complicated though and it is hard to do it